# How do pass variables between tasks in VSTS pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Im working on deploying arm templates via VSTS pipeline. I have a powershell script which gets a subnet id and I need to pass this subnet id value into another task in VSTS. How can i pass variables from a  powershell script to vsts and then pass this to azure resource group deployment task as a parmaeter?

Comment: The logging command (as Rodrigo mentioned) can achieve it. After setting the the variable value from a PowerShell task, the changed value can be used in the following tasks if the build.

Answer (score 24):

You can set a new variable in your powershell and then pass it to VSTS, so that it can be used in one of the next tasks, like this.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
```

This will create a new environment variable called 'sauce' (first example) with value 'crushed tomatoes'.

On your next task you can read it using $(sauce) in your task configuration screen or $env:sauce in a powershell script.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch for more info about how to use it.

Comment: Here are the docs: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion by @Rodrigo Werlang would work, but the set variable would be scoped to the job the task setting it is in.
As of today, this is a known limitation and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell#set-in-script).

> To define or modify a variable from a script, use the task.setvariable logging command. **Note that the updated variable value is scoped to the job being executed, and does not flow across jobs or stages**. Variable names are transformed to upper-case, and the characters "." and " " are replaced by "_".